# C# WPF DataGrid Binding Not Working with Observable Collection

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, datagrid

I've got an Observable Collection with Channel Objects inside. I tried to bind this Observable Collection to a DataGrid like following:

XAML:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="45" Margin="30,10,30,255" ItemsSource="{Binding MGWChannels[0], Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                      AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" >
                                <DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Max Retries" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding MGWChannels[0].MaxRetries, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}}" />
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Backoff Time GW Unreachable" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding MGWChannels[0].BotwUnreachable, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Backoff Time GW Busy" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding MGWChannels[0].BotwMGWBusy, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Backoff Time GW Error" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding MGWChannels[0].BotwMGWError, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}}"/>
                                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Strategy" Width="*"/>
                                </DataGrid.Columns>
                            </DataGrid>
```

Observable Collection in ViewModel:

```
private ObservableCollection<Channel> _mgwChannels;


public ObservableCollection<Channel> MGWChannels
{
    get
    {
        return this._mgwChannels;
    }
    set
    {
        this._mgwChannels = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged("MGWChannels");

    }
}
```

Unfortunately it didn't work out like expected - since in the Observable Collection are 3 Objects I wanted to make 3 DataGrids and bind them with [0], [1] and [2]. Without the [0] it is working but puts all 3 Objects into the List and I only want to display one object per datagrid and not all of them.

Why is it not working? What am I missing out?

Comment: It does not really make sense to put the three objects into an ObservableCollection if you only want to look at them individually. I would recommend using three properties and bind to them without indexer.

Comment: @MaSiMan aight thanks for the answer, i think this should work! :)

Comment: As a note, setting `Mode=TwoWay` on the ItemsSource Binding is pointless. It has no effect.

Comment: And an ObservableCollection is certainly also pointless, since you apparently never add or remove elements, or at least don't need to be notified about. Use three properties of type `List<Channel>` or `IEnumerable<Channel>` that each contain a single element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your xaml should look like below xaml.

1. No indexer is required because you need to bind the collection to DataGrid. If you wish to display just one object then you have to create another collection having single object.
2. While binding the property, no need to look for ViewModel because these properties should be inside the object of collection.

   ```
   private ObservableCollection<ApplicationUser> firstMGWChannel;
   public ObservableCollection<ApplicationUser> FirstMGWChannel

   {
       get
       {
           return new ObservableCollection<ApplicationUser>() { MGWChannels[0] };
       }
   }
   ```

Xaml -

```
     <DataGrid Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="5" Height="45" Margin="30,10,30,255" ItemsSource="{Binding FirstMGWChannel, Source={StaticResource MainWindowViewModel}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" CanUserAddRows="False" RowHeaderWidth="0" >
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Max Retries" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding MaxRetries }" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Backoff Time GW Unreachable" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding BotwUnreachable }"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Backoff Time GW Busy" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding BotwMGWBusy }"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Backoff Time GW Error" Width="auto" Binding="{Binding BotwMGWError }"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Strategy" Width="*"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but as already mentioned (maybe not clear enough), I tried this already but it displays too much. In MGWChannels there are 3 Channel Objects and I just want to display one Object per DataGrid - thats why I tried it with MGWChannels[0]